# Runner.app file is not found while analyzing

Tags: flutter, xcode, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a build as usual, but facing an error

file not found: /U[image]Users/elenaepstejn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bcajezpqzdmbsmgtytqtbbjywjnh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app//Runner

Even though I checked and saw that Runner file is in the project folder.

What should I do in order to xCode to see the file?

Thank you for any help!